# Why can't I receive UDP packets more than once with Boost ASIO?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

HINT: This works if I instantiate the `io_context` inside the `for` loop.

I know this code looks a little goofy, but it's a simplified version of code that's bigger and has this structure. Why can't I receive a second packet with the below code? It works fine with `bool synch = true;`. Here's the output I get:

```
iteration 0
receive udp
posted receive
got a packet
iteration 1
receive udp
posted receive
```

I have to hit Ctrl-c to quit. I expect to see "got a packet" a second time.

The receiver:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ip = asio::ip;

using ip::udp;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using boost_ec = boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioContext;

    std::array<char, 65500> buffer;
    auto asioBuffer = asio::buffer(buffer);

    bool synch = false;

    udp::endpoint remoteEndpoint;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        cout << "iteration " << i << endl;

        auto recvSocket = udp::socket(ioContext,
                                      udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 9090));

        if (synch) {
            recvSocket.receive_from(asioBuffer, remoteEndpoint);
            cout << "received a packet" << endl;
        } else {
            std::function<void(const boost_ec&, size_t)> impl =
                [&](const boost_ec &, size_t packetSize) {

                    if (packetSize > 0) {
                        cout << "got a packet" << endl;
                        return;
                    }

                    cout << "receive udp" << endl;

                    recvSocket.async_receive_from(asioBuffer,
                                                  remoteEndpoint,
                                                  impl);
                    cout << "posted receive" << endl;
                };

            impl(boost_ec(), 0);

            while (ioContext.poll() == 0) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The sender:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ip = asio::ip;
namespace chrono = std::chrono;

using ip::udp;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::array<char, 65500> buffer;
    asio::io_context ioContext;

    auto socket = udp::socket(ioContext);
    socket.open(udp::v4());

    auto endpoint = udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 9090);

    size_t packetsSent = 0;
    size_t bytesSent = 0;

    const double APPROX_BYTES_PER_SEC = 1e6;
    const auto CHECK_INTERVAL = chrono::microseconds(100);

    auto beforeStart = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto start = beforeStart;
    size_t bytesSentSinceStart = 0;

    while (true) {
        auto now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto timePassed = now - start;
        if (timePassed > CHECK_INTERVAL) {
            auto expectedTime = chrono::duration<double>(bytesSentSinceStart /
                                                         APPROX_BYTES_PER_SEC);
            if (expectedTime > timePassed) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(expectedTime - timePassed);
            }
            start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
            bytesSentSinceStart = 0;
        }

        bytesSent += socket.send_to(asio::buffer(buffer), endpoint);
        bytesSentSinceStart += buffer.size();
        ++packetsSent;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/restart.html) is the key:

`void restart();`

> This function must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the io_context being stopped or running out of work.

So the above code needs to call `restart` after every `poll` that results in `ioContext.stopped()` being true, and it becomes true when the ioContext no longer has anything attached to it waiting to happen.